# Tooltip on click of a button

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I'm using [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) to copy some text from a `textarea`, and that's working fine, but I want to show a tooltip saying "Copied!" if it was successfully copied like they do in the example given on their website.

Here's an example of it working without showing a tooltip: https://jsfiddle.net/5j50jnhj/

Comment: You will have to create a tooltip using HTML/CSS, bootstrap has a built in one. Then you can hide/show it depending on success/failure of the copying.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Clipboard.js creator here. So Clipboard.js is not opinionated about user feedback which means it doesn't come with a tooltip solution.

But here's an example of how you can integrate it with Bootstrap's Tooltip.

```js
// Tooltip

$('button').tooltip({
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom'
});

function setTooltip(message) {
  $('button').tooltip('hide')
    .attr('data-original-title', message)
    .tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('button').tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
}

// Clipboard

var clipboard = new Clipboard('button');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  setTooltip('Copied!');
  hideTooltip();
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  setTooltip('Failed!');
  hideTooltip();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-clipboard-text="1">Click me</button>
```

Comment: How would you implement this with multiple buttons on 1 page that all copy from different `textarea`s?

Comment: I think your solution isn't good if there are some clipboard buttons on your page

Comment: The above code does not seem to work with the latest Bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: @Zeno - Does anything special need to be configured with your clipboard code to hand a list of items on a page, each with a copy button?

Answer (score 16):

I do it like it

HTML :

```
<button class="test" data-clipboard-text="1">Button 1</button>
<button class="test" data-clipboard-text="1">Button 2</button>
```

JS :

```
$('.test').tooltip({
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom'
});

function setTooltip(btn, message) {
  btn.tooltip('hide')
    .attr('data-original-title', message)
    .tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip(btn) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
}

var clipboard = new Clipboard('.test');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    var btn = $(e.trigger);
  setTooltip(btn, 'Copied');
  hideTooltip(btn);
});
```

With jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/hs48sego/1/

Comment: This answer is better.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, since it works with multiple buttons.

Answer (score 3):

```css
*[tooltip]:focus:after {
  content: attr(tooltip);
  display:block;
  position: absolute;    
}
```

```html
<button tooltip="I'm tooltip">Button</button>
<br><br>
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" tooltip = "I'm tooltip">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a js fiddle that implements this the way the website does it, I stole the source code: https://jsfiddle.net/bmbs7yco/

the main components to the solution are:

```
function showTooltip(elem, msg) {
    elem.setAttribute('class', 'btn tooltipped tooltipped-s');
    elem.setAttribute('aria-label', msg);
}

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.info('Action:', e.action);
  console.info('Text:', e.text);
  console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
    showTooltip(e.trigger, 'Copied!');
  e.clearSelection();
});
```

and adding their primer.css.  A less lazy method would be to extract the classes from the css you need.

Comment: The above code does not seem to work with the latest Bootstrap 3.3.7.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work, if you have some buttons and etc:

```
function setTooltip(e,message) {
  $(e.trigger).tooltip({
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom'
});
$(e.trigger).tooltip('hide')
 .attr('data-original-title', message)
 .tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(e.trigger).tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
}

// Clipboard

var clipboard = new Clipboard('button');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  setTooltip(e,'Copied!');
  hideTooltip(e);
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  setTooltip(e,'Failed!');
  hideTooltip(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Menucool JavaScript Tooltip. It leaves to the triggering element to decide how to launch the tooltip:

```
<span onclick="tooltip.pop(this, 'Hello world!')">
    Click me
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Only Solution**

[Githubs Primer tooltips](https://github.com/primer) is an excellent solution. 
Usage:

```
npm install --save primer-tooltips
```

Copy the node_modules/primer-tooltips/build/build.css file to a convenient location and then link to it in your HTML. (Consider renaming it a more convenient name e.g. `primer-tooltips.css`). You'll have to edit the build.css file by commenting out the `.tooltipped:hover::before,.tooltipped:hover::after,` pseudo selectors to achieve the on click effect.

Assuming you have clipboardJS already set up, add the following attributes to your copy button:

```
<button 
    class="tooltipped tooltipped-s tooltipped-align-left-1 border p-2 mb-2 mr-2 float-left" 
    aria-label="copied!">
copy
</button>
```

That's it!