# small alert for copy to clipboard in clipboard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clipboard.js

I have an Email address in my page and I want when user clicks on it, then the Email address would be copied to the clip board and with small alert(like attached) it shows user in a small label near the box that it copied to clipboard,

I used https://clipboardjs.com/ to implement my goal.
it copied to clipboard fine, but the problem is that it doesn't show user that it copied to clipboard after clicks on it,

[image]

my code if needed:

javascript

```
  new Clipboard('.btn');
```

html

```
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="test@test.com">
                        test@test.com
</button>
```

Appreciate any suggestion

Comment: any working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the tooltip is not a part of the `clipboard.js`. If you look at the source code of the page, you can see that `tooltip.js` is been added and configured in `demo.js`.

All you need to do is add a tooltip library or function just like the demo page and use it on button click.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, its correct. would you mind if suggest me a tool tip library to add in my project?

Comment: You can just use the one the demo clipboardjs website is using. It is a simple one. And if my answer helped you, Please don't' forget to select it as the Answer :)

Comment: this link was helpful and also thank you to guide me there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798967/tooltip-on-click-of-a-button